# error when convert onPress() FlatButton to function dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I have onPressed() code like this

```
RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Scan'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
                    setState(() {
                      this.barcode = barcode;
                    });
                  } on PlatformException catch (error) {
                    if (error.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.barcode =
                            'Camera Permission denied';
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        this.barcode = 'Error: $error';
                      });
                    }
                  }
                },
              ),
```

but, i want to make this button to navbar, so, I make function from this code like this

```
Future<String> onScan() async {
  try {
    String barcode;
    barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    barcode = barcode;
  } on PlatformException catch (error) {
    if (error.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
      barcode = 'Camera permission denied';
    } else {
      barcode = 'Error: $error';
    }
  }
}
```

but I get error the function cannot read barcode variable in catcth expression. how I fix this? please help me

Comment: Have you tried moving `String barcode` above the `try {` line?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```dart
Future<String> onScan() async {

  try {
    var scannedCode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    setState((){
      this.barcode = scannedCode;
    });
  } on PlatformException catch (error) {
    if (error.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
      setState((){
        this.barcode = 'Camera permission denied';
      });

    } else {
      setState((){
        this.barcode = 'Error: $error';
      });

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @VyscoZyza Cou you edit your question and show us your whole class?